# How to add data to an array from text box/s?

Tags: javascript

I'm fairly stuck on this, I'm playing catchup on course work.
How do I go about adding values to an array using string from text boxes on the page?

```
var book = [
    {
        "name":"Book 1",
        "publisher":"Publisher 1",
        "isbn":"ISBN 1"
    },
    {
        "name":"Book 2",
        "publisher":"Publisher 2",
        "isbn":"ISBN 2"
    },
    {
        "name":"Book 3",
        "publisher":"Publisher 3",
        "isbn":"ISBN 3"
    },
];

book.push({"name":"Moby Dick","publisher":"Ryan Spain","isbn":"00147097"});
```

I know I can push it into the array but I want to add values to name, publisher and isbn from values attained from text boxes in HTML.

Comment: What you have is a JavaScript array containing JavaScript objects. Nothing what you posted has anything to do with JSON.

Comment: What's the actual issue? You haven't posted any attempt to use the text input values. Where exactly are you stuck? How to get references to the input elements? How to get their values? How to use that value as property value (which is as simple as `{name: textInputValue}`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### EDIT: Adding information

Imagine you have three inputs with the following ids "name", "publisher", "isbn".

```
var name = document.getElementById('name');
var pub = document.getElementById('publisher');
var isbn = document.getElementById('isbn');
```

You could add a button when the user is ready to add a book to your list:

```
<button id="add">Add</button>

var button = document.getElementById('add');
```

Then you could add an onclick:

```
button.onclick = function(){
  book.push({'name': name.value, 'publisher': pub.value, 'isbn':isbn.value});
}
```

### Getting information:

Is how you would do it.

```
book[0].name = "Book test";
```

You could loop through all your books and update them one by one:

```
for(var i = 0; i < book.length; i++){
   book[i].name = "Book " + i;
   //etc
}
```

Comment: What makes you think the OP wants to modify an existing entry?

Comment: Because he already knows how to add an entry.. "book.push({"name":"Moby Dick","publisher":"Ryan Spain","isbn":"00147097"});"

Comment: I think the problem is rather with getting the values from the text inputs. But the question is not very clear.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity. @Grimbode has the idea. I want to take in 3 pieces of information. The book name, publisher and ISBN from 3 separate text boxes. Then apply the strings in these text boxes to a new  object in this JS array.

Comment: @RyanSpain better this way?

Comment: @Grimbode Couldn't have put it better myself, literally. Exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks!